# Can you install Ubuntu on a Windows 8 laptop without CD/DVD or USB drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, laptop

I have an Acer Aspire laptop running Windows 8.1. I do not have a CD/DVD drive nor a USB stick. What I would like to know is how to install Ubuntu on a partition of your main hard drive without a CD/DVD or USB drive. I've looked all over the web and haven't found anything.

Comment: If it's urgent and you can't have access to a USB stick have you considered running Ubuntu from a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda tricky, but I'm sure its possible. You should try to install [GRUB4DOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/) Then you'll need a try with [this](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/map.htm#hd32) commands or better add a boot entry to **menu.lst** file placed in a root directory of your hard drive, something like:

```
title Boot My Ubuntu ISO file NOW!
find --set-root /ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
map /ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso quiet splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
boot
```

I'm not 100% sure that will work fine, however for me it's definitely worth to try. ISO file should be placed in root directory. Remember you will need a free partition where you be able to install Ubuntu. If you doesn't have partition for Ubuntu but you have space on it I would try changing size of it and make a new one with Gparted tool in Ubuntu Live. Try to not erase your Windows 8 if you doesn't want it.